# Laravel: Accessing PHP from upper view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

First Laravel Project.
I made a `DB::select` statement in the upper "master" layer, but when I want to access it from the lower layer I get "variable not defined message.

Master layer:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html class="html">
    <head>
    <?php $options=DB::select('select * from options'); ?>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link href="media/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
.
.
.
```

Other layer:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Inventory')
@section('main')
@parent
<?php 
$thumbnails=$options[0]->thumbnails; 
?>
.
.
.
```

Output:

> ErrorException in a9ef8ce5f32a327198559f3667e4271b90435dc6.php line 5:
>   Undefined variable: options (View:
>   /var/www/html/project/laravel/leltar/resources/views/inventory.blade.php)

What did I wrong?

Comment: It's not generally advised to include db queries and such within the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you wanted to access $options variable on any given view. You can achieve that by sharing it across all views.

Add the following code to your **App\Providers\AppServiceProvider** `boot()` function

```
View::share('options', DB::select('select * from options'));
```

Don't forget to import

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

on the top.

Comment: Glad I could help :)